# Fetching multiple rows using mysql LIKE query. wrks in mysql but not in php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my mysql query:

```
select studentID from GameMaster where hobbies like '%baseball%' and hobbies like '%basketball%';
```

hobbies field Type- LongText  .

This fetches two values in mysql. S1001,S1002

When I use this in PHP code, first row is only got.

Here is my php code

```
$sSQL="select studentID from GameMaster where hobbies like '%baseball%' and hobbies like '%basketball%'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sSQL);

 $numberOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($numberOfRows>0) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfRows; $i++) {

      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     $csv_output .= $row[$i].",";
     }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}   
print $csv_output;
```

$csv_output value is S1001,,

As you can see, the second one is empty. Is the loop wrong? I am exporting this value to app inventor.

Comment: See normalisation.

Comment: the answer you expect is "S1001,S1002," right?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't loop through the $row, it is always in the first position!
instead of `$row[$i]` it should be `$row[0]` or `$row['studentID']`

```
if ($numberOfRows>0) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfRows; $i++) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $csv_output .= $row['studentID'].",";
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}
```

instead of the for loop you could also use a while loop:

```
if ($numberOfRows>0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $csv_output .= $row['studentID'].",";
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sSQL="select studentID from GameMaster where hobbies like '%baseball%' or hobbies like '%basketball%'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sSQL);

$numberOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($numberOfRows>0) 
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfRows; $i++)
    {
        $csv_output .= $row[$i].",";
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}   
print $csv_output;
```

Comment: Nothing worked.  mysqli_fetch_array($result); and $row["studentID"]